# Regex selecting and substituting strings between commas does not include commas as intended

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to replace the words one two and three with the specified string. I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
import re

string = "one,two,three,"

string = re.sub(r',?(.*?),+','aA', string)

print(string)
```

Returns

```
aAaAaA
```

But I want it to return `aA,aA,aA,`. I have tried several different commands without succeeding to include the commas.

As far as I am concerned the selection should be inside the parentheses and the commas should therefore not be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

> Why my code doesn't work

You take a string and search for all non-overlapping substrings meeting the `',?(.*?),+'` pattern (*zero or one `,`, (captured into Group 1) any zero or more chars other than line break symbols, 1 or more commas*) and then replace all these matches with `Aa`. It is only logical there no commas, as they got matched and *consumed* with `,+`.

> As far as I am concerned the selection should be inside the parentheses and the commas should therefore not be substituted.

No, if you want to make any replacements inside a captured group, you need to use `re.sub` with a callback method inside (or a lambda), see [this rather useless demo](http://ideone.com/GyzNVx) only showing the functionality:

```
import re
def repl(m):
    return "{0}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1), re.sub(r'\w+', 'Aa', m.group(2)), m.group(3))
string = "one,two,three,"
print(re.sub(r'(,?)(.*?)(,+)',repl, string))
print(re.sub(r'(,?)(.*?)(,+)', lambda m: "{0}{1}{2}".format(m.group(1), re.sub(r'\w+', 'Aa', m.group(2)), m.group(3)), string))
```

There are other ways to get what you need, even a non-regex one.

- Non-regex way: split with `,`, and replace each non-empty chunk with `Aa` and join back with `,`
- Fixing your regex: remove `,?` since `.*` will match it anyway, use `.*?(?=,)` with `(?=,)` being a positive lookahead that *requires the presence* of a comma, but *does not consume it*, i.e. does not make it part of a match
- Use capturing and backreferences: `r'.*?(,+)'` features a capturing group that matches 1 or more commas and `.*?` just matches lazily any 0+ chars other than line break ones, up to the first `,`, and `r'aA\1'` replacement will replace that whole match with `aA` and the commas saved in Group 1
- Easiest: replace all 1+ ASCII letter chunks (matched with `'[a-z]+'` and `flags=re.I` to make it case insensitive) with `aA` pattern.

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/6Xw0BU):

```
import re
string = "one,two,three,"
res = ",".join(["Aa" if x else "" for x in string.split(",")]) # non-regex way
print(res)
print(re.sub(r'.*?(?=,)',r'aA', string))  #regex: fixed version
print(re.sub(r'.*?(,+)',r'aA\1', string)) #regex: capturing and backreferences
print(re.sub(r'[a-z]+',r'aA', string, flags=re.I)) # a very simple, shortest possible working regex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative character class `[^,]+` as regex:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'[^,]+', 'aA', string)
aA,aA,aA,
```

`[^,]+` will match 1 or more of any character that is not a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a-zA-Z]+ to match and replace all letters of the alphabet.

This code worked for me;

```
import re

string = "one,two,three,"

string = re.sub("[a-zA-Z]+","aA",string)

print(string)
```